# jquery checkall button and uncheckall button to select other checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please anyone tell me how to set check all and uncheck all when i check single checkbox one by one after all check , the above checkall and uncheck all is checked that is why he is checked. here is the Code im currently using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.checkall').click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
        $('.uncheckall').prop('checked',false);
        console.log(checkedValues);
    });
    $('.uncheckall').click(function(){
         $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
         $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
    $('.single').on('click',function(){
        if($('.single:checked').length == $('.single').length){
            $('.checkall').prop('checked',true);
            $('.uncheckall').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('.checkall').prop('checked',false);
            $('.uncheckall').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
)<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jquery checked</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>checked all</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="checkall">
<label>unchecked all</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="uncheckall">
<div>
<p>select</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats wrong with your code it selects or unselects all

Comment: when i selected all checkbox single why above uncheckall and checkall checkbox is selected

Comment: yes see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46798956/8749048

Comment: hope it helped!

Comment: see this example: https://codepen.io/Ferhad/pen/wgwpjW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple Toggle Boxes:

```js
function toggle(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
      for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
      for(var checkbox in checkboxes)
        checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    }
    </script>

    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
```

## Customized to your boxes:

```js
$(".checkall").on("click",function(){
  $("input.single").prop("checked",$(this).is(":checked"));
  $("input.uncheckall").prop("checked",(!$(this).is(":checked")));
});
$(".uncheckall").on("click",function(){
     $("input.single").prop("checked",!($(this).is(":checked")));
     $("input.checkall").prop("checked",!($(this).is(":checked")));
});
$(".single").on("click",function(){
   if($(".single:checked").length>0){
     $("input.checkall").prop("checked",true);
     $("input.uncheckall").prop("checked",false);
     }
   else{
     $("input.uncheckall").prop("checked",true);
       $("input.checkall").prop("checked",false);
     }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>checked all</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="checkall">
<label>unchecked all</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="uncheckall">
<div>
<p>select</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check123" class="single">
```

**To change labels for check all/uncheck all on toggle:
See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq958k3s/147) And implement it I am still working and will have a code finished and implimented here on this post soon!**
Here is Fiddle embed:

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/kq958k3s/147/embed/result/"></script>
```

***Thank You!***
Another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/4925/):

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/4925/embed/result/"></script>
```

Comment: plz send code that first that is helful...input:checkbox.single

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Did this help? if so accept the answer. Only if it really helped you though!

Comment: yes its helpful but not this , you send before plzz send again that code..

Comment: $('input:checkbox.single').prop('checked',true);
        $('.uncheckall').prop('checked',false);

Comment: accept the answet if you implement correctly...and upvote if have not already

Comment: ok its good but when i click single button then not check checkall box plzz solve and similarly uncheckall case

Comment: when i uncheck all single button why check uncheckall box

Comment: ok plzz solved and send code me otherwise this code is helpful some

Comment: I think i solved it i made a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kq958k3s/147/